# pip install with private requirements fails

Tags: python, git, ssh, pip, bitbucket

I have the following requirements.txt file:

```
git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../...git@4.19.0#subdirectory=py 
git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../...git@c99b7f6f372c92832eecfb90663833ef1fd3dc62
git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../...git@45d2999ce5f6eba5dd728414073a10d1c50616a2
git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../....git@1ba2781cd2beae6d23218565c395b633b0eb5328
```

When I try to install it however, it fails:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting git+ssh://****@bitbucket.org/.../...git@4.19.0#subdirectory=py (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Cloning ssh://****@bitbucket.org/.../...git (to revision 4.19.0) to c:\users\...\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-t9_wrhxh
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@bitbucket.org/.../...git' 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-t9_wrhxh' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Other colleagues are able to install requirements... what causes this? If I clone in the same was as shown by that error message it works fine:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../....git
Cloning into '...'... 
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/.../.ssh/id_rsa': 
remote: Counting objects: 2053, done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1648/1648), done. 
remote: Total 2053 (delta 1279), reused 385 (delta 200) 
Receiving objects: 100% (2053/2053), 1.88 MiB | 611.00 KiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (1279/1279), done.
```

Comment: Does the normal git clone with ssh url work on the same host?

Comment: @ASR I used git clone git@bitbucket.org:.../...git and it worked. Which means that I replaced one / with :, I left out the git+ssh:// part, and whatever is after the @ symbol. However, by doing that I am missing the specified parameters after the @ symbol, which lead to missing files or cloning more files.

Comment: @AD7six The requirements.txt works. A colleague of mine did the same procedure I followed and did not receive any errors. I didn't understand how to use your suggested command. If it's possible, could you write it as a full example? Should I maybe run git clone --depth 1 git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../...git -b 4.19.0 ? And what about the other 3 examples that do not seem to have parameter names? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @AD7six I run `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/....git@4.19.0#subdirectory=py` and I received the following error: `Repository ....git@4.19.0#subdirectory=py not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: @AD7six I run `(myEnv) C:\Users\...>git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/indoors/....git`
And the result was:
`Cloning into '...'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/.../.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 2053, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1648/1648), done.
remote: Total 2053 (delta 1279), reused 385 (delta 200)
Receiving objects: 100% (2053/2053), 1.88 MiB | 611.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1279/1279), done.`
I retrieved files of the repository, seems it worked, but what about the tags after the word git?

Comment: @AD7six So there is not a problem with the `requirements.txt` file, but because a passphrase is required during cloning, it fails? How can I resolve this?

Comment: @PantelisKaniouras https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Enter+passphrase+for+key

Comment: @AD7six I created a new ssh key that didn't require a passphrase and it worked.. Unbelievable. Thank you very much for your help. I will try to figure out how to include passphrases in these files. I wish you a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
...
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: 
   git clone -q 'ssh://****@bitbucket.org/.../...git' 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-t9_wrhxh'
   Check the logs for full command output.
```

This line from running pip install includes the command being executed. It is just a normal `git clone` writing to a temporary directory (which can be ignored) that is failing. The `-q` (quiet) flag is suppressing some of the output.

```
$ git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../....git
...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/.../.ssh/id_rsa':
```

This line from cloning directly indicates that whilst the clone is successful the key used to authenticate with bitbucket has a passphrase. When cloning in an interactive process, git is able to prompt for it - but that is not true in a *none* interactive process (such as pip).

## Solution

There are multiple ways to solve this but the simplest would be:

- Create a new ssh key pair *without* a passphrase
- Add this key to your bitbucket account
- Configure ssh to use this key with bitbucket.org

```
Host bitbucket.org
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/no_passphrase.id_rsa
```

- success